# How can I change the standard spring logic to display the error on the login page that I need?

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, spring-mvc, spring-security

When I throw my custom exception (AccountNotActivatedException) in the loadUserByUsername method, Spring wraps it in an InternalAuthenticationServiceException. In general, almost any exception in this method is packaged into it.
The problem is that such an exception cannot be handled using @ExceptionHandler (or any other, because it wraps all exceptions in it) and it has its own behavior.
And I need to understand exactly what error the user encountered during authentication in order to display it on the view.
Each situation should have its own error text to indicate to the user what exactly is wrong.

And now, as I understand it, in case of an error, it simply passes the “error” parameter to the request and returns the login page, I can no longer interact with it.

```
@Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        boolean accountNonExpired = true;
        boolean credentialsNonExpired = true;
        boolean accountNonLocked = true;

        User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

        if(user==null){
            throw  new UsernameNotFoundException("Unable to login. The email or password is incorrect");
        }
        if (!user.isEnabled()) {
            throw new AccountNotActivatedException(
                    "This account is not activated. " +
                            "To complete the registration, follow the link in the letter that was sent to your email address. " +
                            "We also recommend you check the \"Spam\" category."
            );
        }
        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                user.getUsername(),
                user.getPassword(),
                user.isEnabled(),
                accountNonExpired,
                credentialsNonExpired,
                accountNonLocked,
                Collections.singleton(user.getRole()));
    }
```

This is my Spring Configuration

```
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
   http
           .anonymous(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
           .authorizeHttpRequests(authorize -> authorize
                   .requestMatchers(PathRequest
                           .toStaticResources()
                           .atCommonLocations())
                   .permitAll()
                   .requestMatchers("/book/{bookId}/testResults")
                   .authenticated()
                   .anyRequest().permitAll())
           .formLogin(login ->login
                   .loginPage("/login")
                   .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                   .permitAll())
           .logout(logout ->logout
                   .logoutUrl("/logout")
                   .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                   .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                   .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                   .permitAll());
                /*.oauth2Login( oauth2->oauth2
                        .loginPage("/login"));*/
                      /*  .defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                        .userInfoEndpoint(userInfo-> userInfo
                                .oidcUserService(oidcUserService())));*/
   return http.build();
}
```

P.S. I would also like to ask if it is true that Spring itself checks the login/password without me or should I do it myself, accept data from the form and access the database and check this data using the controller method.
Now I just use the Post method to transfer information to the /login endpoint and do not have PostMapping for this resource

Comment: Handing out friendly authentication messages to end users is not recommended as this can aid users with malicious intent. If someone iterates user logins they can till what is an active user and who is not. That is why spring wraps all exceptions that are security related as this is best practice. You should only display a generic message ”something went wrong either try again or contact support”.

Comment: Okay, but then how can I notify the user so that he activates the account?

Comment: i dont know, like other sites do? notify via an email during sign up? or as i said, have a generic message that just says "contact support"

Answer (score 0):

I changed the behavior of this handler and everything works as it should, but I'm not sure about the security. How permissible and safe is this?

```
public class CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {

    private final RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String errorMessage = determineErrorMessage(exception);

        redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, "/login?error=" + errorMessage);
    }

    private String determineErrorMessage(AuthenticationException exception) {
        if (exception instanceof DisabledException) {
            return "This account is not activated. " +
                    "To complete the registration, follow the link in the letter that was sent to your email address. " +
                    "We also recommend checking the 'Spam' category.";
        } else if (exception instanceof BadCredentialsException) {
            return "Invalid username or password.";
        } else {
            return "Authentication failed: " + exception.getMessage();
        }
    }
}


@GetMapping("/login")
    public String loginPage(@RequestParam(name = "error", required = false) String error, Model model) {
        if (error != null) {
            model.addAttribute("errorMessage", error);
        }
        return "login-page";
    }
```